# Is it true that $(\kappa = 0,1$ or infinite$)$ $\Leftrightarrow (\kappa^\mu = \kappa$ for all $\mu < \kappa)$?

Tags: set-theory, logic

Clearly the statement holds for all cardinals $\kappa$ up to $\aleph_0$ - it is well known that $|\mathbb{N}^n| = |\mathbb{N}|$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Assuming the generalised continuum hypothesis, it seems that one may be able to prove such a thing inductively. However, does this hold without assuming $\mathsf{GCH}$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By [König's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)) you have
$$\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)}>\kappa$$
for any $\kappa \ge \aleph_0$.

In particular, if you have $\mu=\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)<\kappa$, then you get $\kappa^\mu>\kappa$, which gives a counterexample to the claim from the question.

The inequality $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)<\kappa$ is true for any [singular cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_cardinal) $\kappa$; for example, for $\kappa=\aleph_\omega$ you have $\operatorname{cf}(\aleph_\omega)=\aleph_0$.

---

Under GCH you can still prove that the claim is true for *regular* $\kappa$. Here is [Corollary 1.7.5](https://books.google.com/books?id=wlqSgRJ42-EC&pg=PA74) from Holz, Michael; Steffens, Karsten; Weitz, Edmund: *Introduction to Cardinal Arithmetic*; Birkhäuser 1999.

> **Corollary 1.7.5.** Assume (GCH). Then for all cardinals $\kappa\ge2$ and $\lambda\ge\omega$,
>   $$\kappa^\lambda =
>   \begin{cases}
>     \kappa & \text{if }\lambda<\operatorname{cf}(\kappa), \\
>     \kappa^+ & \text{if }\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)\le\lambda<\kappa, \\
>     \lambda^+ & \text{if }\kappa\le\lambda.
>   \end{cases}
> $$

---

Without GCH, the equality can fail for regular cardinals. For example, in the Cohen's model for ZFC+$\neg$CH we have $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$. This gives us $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2>\aleph_1$. (In fact, whenever we have $2^\mu=2^\kappa$, then $\kappa^\mu\ge 2^\mu=2^\kappa > \kappa$.)

Comment: Thanks Martin. I'm guessing it's not true, even for regular cardinals, without assuming GCH?

Comment: @JordanMitchellBarrett Indeed, GCH is equivalent to the claim for successor cardinals.